# What do I use instead of PyString_AsString when loading a python module in 3.3

Tags: python, c++, python-module

I am trying to load a function from python in one of my c++ programs using this function

```
char * pyFunction(void)
{
    char *my_result = 0;
    PyObject *module = 0;
    PyObject *result = 0;
    PyObject *module_dict = 0;
    PyObject *func = 0;
    PyObject *pArgs = 0;

    module = PyImport_ImportModule("testPython");
    if (module == 0)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Couldn't find python module");
    }
    module_dict = PyModule_GetDict(module); 
    func = PyDict_GetItemString(module_dict, "helloWorld"); 

    result = PyEval_CallObject(func, NULL); 
    //my_result = PyString_AsString(result); 
    my_result = strdup(my_result);
    return my_result;
}
```

What should I use instead of PyString_AsString?

Comment: Probably [`PyBytes_AsString`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/bytes.html#PyBytes_AsString). If that's a unicode string then you should first decide which encoding do you want to use and then encode it with [`PyUnicode_Encode`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/unicode.html#PyUnicode_Encode)

Comment: You should also use [`PyObject_CallObject(func, NULL)`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_call#c.PyObject_CallObject) instead of `PyEval_CallObject()`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Depending on the returned type from your `helloWorld()` function, it
could vary so it's best to check it.

To handle a returned `str` (Python 2 `unicode`), then you will need to
encode it. The encoding will depend on your use case but I'm going to
use UTF-8:

```
if (PyUnicode_Check(result)) {
    PyObject * temp_bytes = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(result, "UTF-8", "strict"); // Owned reference
    if (temp_bytes != NULL) {
        my_result = PyBytes_AS_STRING(temp_bytes); // Borrowed pointer
        my_result = strdup(my_result);
        Py_DECREF(temp_bytes);
    } else {
        // TODO: Handle encoding error.
    }
}
```

To handle a returned `bytes` (Python 2 `str`), then you can get the
string directly:

```
if (PyBytes_Check(result)) {
    my_result = PyBytes_AS_STRING(result); // Borrowed pointer
    my_result = strdup(my_result);
}
```

Also, if you receive a non-string object, you can convert it
using [PyObject_Repr()](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Repr), [PyObject_ASCII()](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_ASCII), [PyObject_Str()](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Str), or [PyObject_Bytes()](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Bytes).

So in the end you probably want something like:

```
if (PyUnicode_Check(result)) {
    // Convert string to bytes.
    // strdup() bytes into my_result.
} else if (PyBytes_Check(result)) {
    // strdup() bytes into my_result.
} else {
    // Convert into your favorite string representation.
    // Convert string to bytes if it is not already.
    // strdup() bytes into my_result.
}
```

Comment: Here is my python function: def helloWorld():
    returnData =  "Hello"
    return returnData

Comment: @bbdude95 If that's the case, then the type of `result` will be a `str` (`PyUnicode`) so it's safe to use just that example. But in a real world scenario, it would be best to allow for different types.

Comment: I see some problems. There are quotes around the resultant string and also `\n` is converted to `\\n`.

Comment: @ar2015 That's what `PyObject_Repr()` does (`repr()` on the Python side). You likely want `PyObject_Str()` or `PyObject_Bytes()`.

Comment: @cpburnz, you mean doing the same conversion just without `PyObject_Repr`?

Comment: @ar2015 Yes, doing the same conversion but using a different function such as `PyObject_Str()` (since this conversion gives you unicode, you'll have to encode it to bytes first as seen in my first example).

Comment: This answer is for an ancient Python 3.2 or below. See the kfsone's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

If you were using `PyString_AsString` to get a C-compatible `const char*` representation of what you know to be a `str` object, then in Py3 you can simply use `PyUnicode_AsUTF8`:

```py
    func = PyDict_GetItemString(module_dict, "helloWorld"); 

    result = PyEval_CallObject(func, NULL); 
    const char* my_result = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(result);
```